# How to correctly enqueue stylesheets to Wordpress page templates using 'wp_style_add_data'?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have learned how to use `wp_style_add_data` to add stylesheets for early versions of internet explorer – which is ideal as it only overwrites the necessary CSS rules and takes the rest from my `style.css`.

In addition to my `page.php` I have a second page template that I've named `full-page.php` which is nearly identical, apart from a few changes to the header and a few other small differences.

Because my templates are nearly the same, it seems like overkill to write two long stylesheets when I could do something similar to the `wp_style_add_data` function to only rewrite the ones I need to change.

I had a go at using `wp_style_add_data` to enqueue the stylesheet for my page template. This actually works and takes any styles I add to `style.css` providing they are not already different ones in `full-page.css`.

Here is the code I used:

```
if (is_page_template('page-templates/full-page.php'))  

    { wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-full-page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/full-page.css', array( 'theme_style' ) ); 
      wp_style_add_data( 'theme-full-page' );

} 

else { wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_style_ie8', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/ie8.css', array( 'theme_style' ) ); 
wp_style_add_data( 'theme_style_ie8', 'conditional', 'IE 8' );
```

However, it's also coming up with the following error message.

```
Warning
: Missing argument 3 for wp_style_add_data(), called in /var/sites/l/lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/lucieaverillphotography/functions.php on line 31 and defined in
/var/sites/l/lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php
on line
223
```

I think this is because I've removed the part that tells it to only take effect if the user is viewing the website on IE 8, but I've been researching what I could add instead, and haven't been able to find an answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

I think I've managed to work this out, as it seems to be working now – any changes I make in `style.css` are affecting the other stylesheet `full-page.css`, unless I specify something else in `full-page.css`.

Looking at the code, would this be the correct/best way to write this out? It seems a little lengthy and I have to repeat the stylesheet names a lot, but it also seems to work. I know that there are often different ways of doing things with PHP and I'm wary of causing complications later down the line as I'm building my theme.

if (is_page_template('page-templates/full-page.php'))

```
{ wp_enqueue_style( 'theme_style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

  wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-full-page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/full-page.css', array( 'theme_style' ) ); 
  wp_style_add_data( 'theme-full-page', 'title', 'theme-full-page' );
}
```

Comment: Read [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_style_add_data/#source-code) again. `wp_style_add_data()` requires three arguments.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I think I've solved it after reading that. I've added my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have already enqueued the style, wp_style_add_data() does not enqueue, it adds meta data to an already enqueued style and this function does not allow for empty parameters. see below.

```
if (is_page_template('page-templates/full-page.php')) { 
      wp_enqueue_style( 'lucieaverillphotography_style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'lucieaverillphotography-full-page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/full-page.css', array( 'lucieaverillphotography_style' ) ); 
      //wp_style_add_data( 'lucieaverillphotography-full-page' );  --> not needed & cannot be used without required inputs

}
```

But.....you could combine all your css into a single file and call this as default on all pages (call ie8 specific stylesheets if you want....), this way it can be browser cached and after the 1st visit, your css loads faster...Brush up on CSS specificity and ids/ classes, it will save you a lot of work in the long run!

If you want template specific changes to css you have a couple of options

1. if the css changes are in the article/ page, there will be usually a id/class set unique to that page (or add one yourself).
2. add custom css directly to the template (it works anywhere in the page, wont be popular with standards but for the moment you can put css rules anywhere inside style tags
3. Add a custom class into your header for the body tag, e.g. 
   >

You can then specifically target css in your template...
e.g.

```
 .page-id-2 header{ display: none;} //-->use chrome inspector to see what classes are outputted on each template
```

Comment: Hi David, I'm not sure I follow – if I were to put all of my CSS in one stylesheet, how could I change things in my other page templates? For example, in my `full-page.php` template I have a transparent header, which requires me to change the header to `position:absolute`, whereas on the main template it is set to `position:relative`. How can I do this on a single stylesheet? I might add more page templates later down the line too.

Comment: i updated more information, but as i said read up on css specificity, you will understand it easily enough.

Comment: care to explain the dv?

Comment: Hi David, sorry for the late reply, I think there's possibly a time zone difference. I think I may have solved it with a third argument to the `wp_style_add_data` function. I've pasted it above in my question.

Comment: wp style add data can be removed, its not doing anything for you here. wp_enqueue_style is all you need and as you can see you have enqueued style.css and full-page.css. So any rules set in style.css will remain until and if overwritten in full-page.css

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Looks like I've spent the past couple of days barking up the wrong tree with that one.